# Properly Closing Secondary Form VS Application Exit

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

This is probably going to be a standard question. I have read lots of articles on this but none point out the issue i am having specifically.

I am developing a WinForm and have a "Main Menu" form that is loaded on startup. Within this main are several buttons which open up individual modules (other forms) of the program.

I can open up the form no problem and can close it and re-show the main form no problem. The problem lies when a user hits the (X) in the control box, the application doesnt exit because the main form is still there, but hidden. I know that i could put an application.exit() in the close event of the form. However, then if i have a button that closes the form and wants to unhide the main form, the application will close due to the formclosing event.

Can someone help me understand this principle. I dont think it should be as hard as it seems to me and i dont really want to use Panels.

Thanks in advance.

-Joseph

the following code solved the issue based on the answer provided below

```
private void btnHome_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form f1 = Application.OpenForms[0];
    f1.Visible=true;

    this.Close();
}

private void frmCostControlMain_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    Form f = Application.OpenForms[0]; // The main form
    if (f.Visible==true)
    {
        f.BringToFront();
    }
    else
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: I find it hard to wrap my head around your problem. Could you maybe post some code or a graphic that illustrates your problem to some point

Comment: `if (f.Visible==true)` is the same as `if (f.Visible)` because `f.Visible` is already a Boolean value. Comparing a Boolean value against `true` yields the same Boolean value again. It's like like writing `y = 1 * x;` instead of just writing `y = x;`. The if-statement does not require a comparison, but just a Boolean value. Any expression yielding a Boolean value will do.

Comment: thank you, i will adjust accordingly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the `Application.OpenForms` and see whether some non-hidden forms other than the current form are around. If you only want to check the main form, you can check `Application.OpenForms[0]`. Since it was opened first, it will always be at index 0. From memory:

```
Form_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form f = Application.OpenForms[0]; // The main form
    if (f.Visible) {
        f.BringToFront();
    } else {
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

When the close button is clicked you would first unhide the main form and then close the current form.

Comment: That's kind of the problem. It doesnt matter if the form is hidden or not. If a user hits the (X) on the control box, the application should close regardless. However, if the form is closed VIA code, the application doesn't need to close as i will be re-directing it to another form. The "hidden" portion of that code isnt recognized, "doesnt contain a definition for Hidden" but i could use the "Visible" property maybe

Comment: You said "... when a user hits the (X) in the control box, the application doesnt exit because the main form is still there, but hidden". So, when the X is hit, the main form will be hidden in the closed event. But when you close the form in code, you first unhide the main form, so that in the closed event the main form will not be hidden. Therefore the state `f.Visible` tells you whether X was hit or the form was closed from code.

Comment: Sorry, i had to re-read your answer to get the basis of the intent. Let me try this and see if i can get it work by unhiding the main form before close. Any idea why the usage of "hidden" isnt valid?

Comment: I think the right property is `Visible`. `f.Show()` sets `Visible = true`, `f.Hide()` sets `Visible = false`;

Comment: I was able to get this to work. Thank you very much. I am going to post the final cut. Is this the most efficient way to call a hidden form?

Answer (score 0):

I still don't understand your question, but I guess you could use the 
Application.Exit().
You should then check the arguments of your FormClosed event.
The Close reason is as follows:

Click on [X]:
CloseReason = UserClosing

Application Exit:
CloseReason = ApplicationExitCall

You could then handle it properly

```
private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.ApplicationExitCall) 
    {
        //Application.Exit();
    }
    else if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
    {
        //[X] was pressed
    }
    else 
    {
        //Many other reasons
    }
}
```

I guess there is a much **cleaner way** of handling your problem. **If** you provide a bit **more details**, I think someone would be able to help you along.